# enum class declaration and use of this into another class

Tags: java, enums

Let, I have two classes `FishType` and `Fish`

`FishType` is an enumeration of standard fish classifications, including the following members:

```
{ 
 Shark,
 Ray,
 Eel,
}
```

`Fish` class is:

```
Name : String
Classificiation : FishType
```

So basically, I wanna declare property for **"Fish"** of **'FishType'** enum class

how it can be done in java?

Comment: Fish is a class and FishType should be enum.

Comment: See [the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it like this

```
class Fish{

    enum FishType{
        SHARK,
        RAY,
        EEL
    }

    FishType fishType = FishType.SHARK;
}
```

You can also mark your `enum` class `public` as you do for any other class for visibility. enum is a special class having predefined instances for each of the named constant the enum represents

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Fish {
    private FishType type;
    private String name;

    // ... some methods.
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
public class Fish {
    enum FishType /* Edited */ {
        Shark("Shark"),
        Ray("Ray"),
        Eel("Eel")
    }

    private String name;
    private FishType classification;
}
```

Comment: -1: `FishType` is undefined (since you named it `EntityType`) and without a constructor you can't use additional string names for the enum values.

Comment: @IngoBürk, _without a constructor you can't use additional string names for the enum values_ is that true ? I believe recent java version is supporting this type of code. Which I am using quite often these days.

Comment: In 1.7.0_09 it doesn't work. If you believe it works in any version, please clarify that version (also try compiling your own code to see if it works -- it doesn't for me).